# Water penetrating through slats in my Garador garage door

Tags: waterproofing, garage-door

I have a strip on the floor inside the garage beneath the door and even had a drainage channel on the outside of the door constructed beyond the raised lip on the outside of the door. Rainwater still gets in in large quantities during medium to heavy storms.

I believe this is getting in through the gaps in the design of the door since I can see puddles of water on the metal crossparts on the inside of the garage door still waiting to fall to the ground when the rain has ceased. I have no idea why these gaps are considered to be a good idea but think that I need to fill them in to stop the ingress of water. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Brand/model of the door, and clear, well lit, focused pictures of the whole door and detail shots of these gaps will help us help you by allowing us to see what you see. Please [edit] this info into your question so we can best help you.